# Invoke az function outside your own subscription

Tags: azure, azure-functions

If I have an eventhub in 1 Azure subscription,and an Azure function in a different subscription am I able to call the function and if so is this secure?

Answer (score 1):

The Function created using your Azure subscription A can create a trigger that is listening on the Event Hub created using Azure subscription B.

All you have to do is provide the **correct and valid connection string** from the Event Hub created using subscription B.